# what is the difference between classOf[T] and Class[T]

Tags: scala

I have this code

```
"123".getClass.asInstanceOf[Class[String]]
"123".getClass.asInstanceOf[classOf[String]]//compilation error, classOf not defined
```

However, I can use classOf in this way

```
println(classOf[String])
```

I am little confused here, what is the difference between classOf[T] and Class[T]

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Class[T]` is a type; `classOf[T]` is a value of this type. So you can't use `classOf[String]` as a type parameter (between `[` and `]`), just as you can't write `"123".getClass.asInstanceOf[new Object]`; and you can't use `Class[T]` as a normal argument (between `(` and `)`), just as you can't write `println(String)`.

Answer (score 1):

A `classOf[T]` is a value of type `Class[T]`. In other words, `classOf[T]: Class[T]`. For example:

```
scala> val strClass = classOf[String]
strClass: Class[String] = class java.lang.String

scala> :t strClass
Class[String]
```

This allows one to constrain parameters used in reflective methods:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait Fruit
case class Apple(name: String) extends Fruit
case class Pear(name: String) extends Fruit

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Fruit
defined class Apple
defined class Pear

scala> def fruitFunction(kind: Class[_ <: Fruit]) { println("Fruity...") }
fruitFunction: (kind: Class[_ <: Fruit])Unit

scala> fruitFunction(classOf[Apple])
Fruity...

scala> fruitFunction(classOf[String])
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[String](classOf[java.lang.String])
 required: Class[_ <: Fruit]
       fruitFunction(classOf[String])
```

Answer (score -1):

This are two complete different things: `classOf[]` returns the class of the given argument whereas `Class[]` is an object of the class.

In Java this maps to

```
Class[]    <-> Class<>
classOf[X] <-> X.class
```

Comment: Wrong. `x.getClass()` corresponds to `x.getClass()` in Scala (parentheses optional).

Comment: This is incorrect. `classOf[X]` corresponds to `X.class` in Java - it returns the object of class `Class[X]`.

Comment: Corrected my answer after comments.